# css-in-javascript use in a React component

Tags: css, reactjs

According to this reference https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/css-in-javascript, a styled JS component should be written like this:

```
function MyComponent({ styles }) {
  return (
    <div {...css(styles.container)}>
      Never doubt that a small group of thoughtful, committed citizens can
      change the world. Indeed, it’s the only thing that ever has.
    </div>
  );
}

export default withStyles(() => ({
  container: {
    display: 'inline-block',
  },
}))(MyComponent);
```

I'm trying to write a simple React component like following, without success (I'm receiving a `withStyles is not defined` error):

```
import React from 'react';

const MyComponent = ({styles}) => {
  return (
    <div {...css(styles.container)}>Hello World</div>
  )
}

export default withStyles(() => ({
  container: {
    color: 'red'
  },
}))(MyComponent);
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it possible to use this convention for a React component?

Comment: `withStyles` according to your code IS NOT defined. Are you importing it from the `react-with-styles` library: `import { css, withStyles } from 'react-with-styles';`?

Comment: I found the reference page without knowing that it was part of a bigger project. Thanks for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
const divStyle = {
  color: 'blue',
  fontSize:10px
};

function HelloWorldComponent() {
  return <div style={divStyle}>Hello World!</div>;
}
```

However you can try other better approaches.Please refer to the link below:

https://medium.com/@aghh1504/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822